# How to refresh automatically TextView

Tags: java

I am starting to learn java and I have a question: When I use my following code, eveything works, but I need to click on "margin" to have a result. Is it possibleprice.getText().toString();

```
                cprice.getText().toString();
                double a1=Double.valueOf(price.getText().toString());
                double a2=Double.valueOf(cprice.getText().toString());
                double a3;
                a3 = a1-a2;
                margin.setText(String.valueOf(a3)); to refresh automatically the textview?
```

Comment: Please show your entire program. Should your entire program be too large, create a new program which only includes your problem. Please fix typographical errors in your question too.

Comment: Please add more code about your current implementation. You can update  TextView just by setText(), nothing more in this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` method to update your GUI text.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        margin.setText(String.valueOf(a3));
```

You can find more about `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).